# Unresolved identifier

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I seem to be getting an unresolved identifier in this line of code for dt

```
func moveSprite(sprite: SKSpriteNode, velocity: CGPoint) {
//1
let amountToMove = CGPoint(x: velocity.x * CGFloat(dt),y: velocity.y * CGFloat(dt))
println("Amount to move: \(amountToMove)")
//2
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: sprite.position.x + amountToMove.x, y: sprite.position.y + amountToMove.y)
```

And how do i find the declaration?

Comment: Besides looking for it? Where did you intend to put it? If not declared at function scope, it must be at class scope, or (eww) global scope.

Comment: Can't you Command-Click to get the declaration?

Answer (score 0):

My Googling suggests that you're trying to follow [Ray Wenderlich's Zombie Conga tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-games-by-tutorials). I  don't have access to the tutorial but based on [this Objective-C code](https://github.com/mrhappyasthma/ZombieConga---iOS-Games-By-Tutorials-Project-1/blob/master/ZombieConga/MyScene.m), I think you've missed the fact that `dt` should be an instance variable of type `NSTimeInterval`, and you should set it in the `update` method of your `SKScene` subclass.